# How to show $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} e^{1/z}$ is undefined?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I am looking at proving that $e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$, by using the fact that at such a singularity:
$$ \lim_{z\rightarrow 0} e^{1/z}$$
must be undefined (i.e. not a unique finite value or uniquely infinite). How would be go about showing this?

Comment: What does "uniquely infinite" mean?

Comment: @anomaly i.e. no matter how you approach $z=0$ you will always get $\infty$.

Comment: Look at what happens as you approach zero along the real axis from the left and the right.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider what happens as $z\to 0$ along the positive imaginary axis.